# Can I get the filtered content of the q-table but use reactive variables (or without the ref attribute)

Tags: vuejs3

I am a beginner in quasar and also a beginner in vue3.

I want to get the filtered data of q-table (EX: sum the amount of the current page after filtering and sum the amount of all the pages after filtering)

I have tried using $refs like https://forum.quasar-framework.org/topic/6708/export-only-filtered-data-in-a-q-table/3
In this page, the replies of the people below do not work for me

After querying the data, I found that this may be applicable to Vue2, but it does not work in Vue3 setup (because "this" cannot be used in setup, and $refs cannot be used)

And found that the writing in the quasar official website is effective, https://quasar.dev/vue-components/table#keyboard-navigation

But then I found that the ref attribute EX: ref="tableRef" defined in q-table cannot be a member of the reactive variable EX: ref="data.table.tableRef" , I print data.table.tableRef, it will be find that he is always null

But I have put all the required variables in reactive, and don't want to import ref specifically for this function

I would like to ask if you want to use the ref attribute, you must use the ref variable for access?

I would also like to ask if I want to obtain the data after q-table screening (EX: the amount of the current page after screening and the amount of all pages after screening), is there a better way?(EX:using getCurrentInstance be a better approach?)

Comment: `$refs` has never been reactive - and probably won't be. Also, Vue3 does not require you to use Composition API - you can use Options API just fine (you will have access to `this`) If you want to aggregate data at the bottom - you can use the same trick as https://forum.quasar-framework.org/post/24395

Comment: @IVO GELOV
Thanks a lot for letting us know that $refs has never been reactive

And I currently use ref variables for access

Vue3 is mixed with Vue2's writing, will this be a good thing?
Is the example in the web page irrelevant to filter?

Comment: And I found that although refs seems to need to be connected with ref at present, the bottom layer is also implemented using reactive Proxy. I really can't use a certain method to directly use reactive variables to implement it?

Comment: I tried to comprehend what you wrote but I failed miserably. Are you using Google Translate? DOM is not reactive by nature - if you want to react on DOM changes (e.g. appearing or disappearing of element) you will need to use MutationObserver API. What do you refer by "Vue 3 writing" and "Vue 2 writing" - it's unclear? It's perfectly fine to use Composition API and Options API at the same time - they are not mutually exclusive but the latter is simpler and easier than the former. It's a matter of taste.

Comment: "Vue3 is mixed with Vue2's writing, will this be a good thing?" I thought "Composition API" was Vue3's coding style, and "Options API" was Vue2's coding style, so I asked: Is it good to use Vue2's syntax in Vue3?

Comment: And I answer - there is absolutely no problem mixing both APIs/styles. It's up to the developer's taste and preference which of them to use in his/her particular application.